# Number of matrices with entries in $\{0,1,2\}$ with prescribed row and column sums

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

I want to count the number of $\ell_1\times\ell_2$ matrices with entries in $\{0,1,2\}$ and prescribed sum of entries for each row and column.

For example, there are three $2\times 2$ matrices with row and column sums equal to 2:
$$\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\2&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

There are 21 $3\times 3$ matrices with row and column sums equal to 2 - not listed here, but you can check in GAP using the following command:

```
gap> R:=Filtered(Tuples([0,1,2],3),r->Sum(r)=2);
gap> Q:=Filtered(Tuples(R,3),M->ForAll(TransposedMat(M),r->Sum(r)=2));
gap> Size(Q);
```

I also found a [paper by Wang and Zhang (1997)](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0012365X97001970/1-s2.0-S0012365X97001970-main.pdf?_tid=c34d163d-af2a-48d2-b2f1-11fee8c9aa79&acdnat=1534932035_7ff1698adf959213432a0f84c37ef524) for the number of matrices with entries in $\{0,1\}$ with prescribed row and column sums, so I am wondering how I can extend it to $\{0,1,2\}$.